# Pandoc: applying a style to all images when exporting to docx?

Tags: image, ms-word, formatting, pandoc

I used to ask this question a few years ago, and back then it was not possible to apply a style to all images when exporting to docx using Pandoc.

Today, I wonder whether this still is true? I tried a bit using Pandoc 2.9.x, and images still seem to have applied the generic "Normal" style:

[image: screenshot]

It would be nice to have a style like "Picture" which is applied to each image in the docx. Any way to do this?

Comment: I don't know the docx format very well, but have you seen https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles ? possibly you can also write a lua-filter to add the `custom-style` attribute to all images...

Comment: This looks promising! I could add such styles while formatting the markdown code, before exporting it to docx. It's not the most elegant option (like e.g. CSS' `img { ... }`), but it would work I guess. Thank you!

Comment: well yes, or just write a [filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to transform the document AST... that should be less brittle...

Answer (score 0):

Images by themselves cannot have any style, you have to wrap an image into a block, that can have custom attributes. I replace figure elements with a pair of an image and a caption, something like this:

```
funFigure = function(element)
    local attrfigure = pandoc.Attr( "", { }, {{"custom-style", "Picture" }} )
    local attrfiguretext = pandoc.Attr( "", { }, {{"custom-style", "Picture Caption" }} )
    local figuretext = pandoc.Div(pandoc.Para(element.content[1].caption), attrfiguretext)
    element.content[1].caption = pandoc.Null
    local figure = pandoc.Div(element, attrfigure)
    return { figure, figuretext }
end
```